# Showing additional information on list elements [Angular]

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am learning Angular, and I try to create a small project. I use the following code:

TS:

```
export class Basic implements OnInit {

  products:any[];
  hide: boolean = true;
  constructor() {
      this.products=[
      {
        name:"Mac Book Pro",
        price:"1000",
        color:"grey"
      },
      {
        name:"iPhone",
        price:"700",
        color:"black"
      }
    ]
 }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  toggle(){
    this.hide=!this.hide;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of products">
    <div (click)="toggle()">{{x.name}}</div>
    <div [hidden]="hide">
        {{x.price}}
        {{x.color}}
    </div>
</div>
```

So, the code produces a list of products. My aim is once I click on one product to get its additional information below it. But I can't figure out how to make it only for one element. Currently, when I press on the first element, it also shows the information for the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have one varibale `hide` for all of items. So you can do that by a extra property say `isOpen` in you model:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of products;">
   <div (click)="toggle(x)">{{x.name}}</div>
   <div [hidden]="!x.isOpen">
      {{x.price}}
      {{x.color}}
   </div>
</div>

  toggle(x){
    x.isOpen = !x.isOpen
  }
```

Here is working sample I created for you: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-unmnww?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This is definitely working. But I am quite confused why :) You are not using anywhere `hide: Array<boolean> = []` and when defining `toggle(x)` I get a type error for x, so I cannot compile. The second is solvable, but for the first one I would kindly ask you if you could explain if the variable is not needed anymore or at what position it is getting new values :D

Comment: Yes you don't need to `hide: Array<boolean> = []` I forgot to remove it.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi thanks for improving my previous answer